# Is there a way to instantiate many classes without typing each explicitly?

Tags: c++

I have multiple classes that each correspond to an API that can be called. I am moving these classes out of one central file into their own individual files so that testing will be easier. Here is the current structure:

```
class Foo : Public Parent{
    //stuff
}
Parent* bar = new Foo(this);
Register(bar);
```

Basically the `Register()` function needs to be called on an instance of each class so that the API can be used in the system.

After moving each class to its own file, here is how I instantiate each class from the central file:

```
Namespace::api0(this);
Namespace::api1(this);
Namespace::api2(this);
//etc
```

(As part of the migration of these classes, the `Register()` function was moved into their constructors)

My question is, is there a way to instantiate each class without explicitly typing the name of each class? Could I somehow group them or find them dynamically through my file structure? We're talking about a very large amount of classes, so finding a more dynamic method would help with future maintenance.

Comment: how solid are your template skills? maybe you can factor some things out with it, since it seems a similar pattern. other possibility would be the preprocessor, creating a macro (not recommended, since the PP should be avoided).

Comment: *"My question is, is there a way to instantiate **each** class **without** explicitly typing **the name** of **each class**?"* - It sounds like you are looking for some voodoo magic... :-).. Quips aside, you'll probably need to write some automated code generator for that.

Comment: @jonas_toth I could make a macro, but how do I avoid having to call that macro for each class? I'll look into templates.

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking since you have posted bits and pieces of code. That leaves a lot to guesswork as to what the current code base looks like and how you would like the final code base to look like.

Comment: There's a design pattern called Abstract Factory that addresses situations like this, it might be worth looking at.

Comment: i have seen code, where you define a macro that does basic stuff, and then include a file will many macro calls. not sure if that would help. and i strongly recommend thinking twice about something like that :)

but all the instantitions can happen in a templated function/class. that must be called with each type still.

Comment: It is possible to make all these classes self-register, however straight approach with all the classes being registered explicitly listed in one place is much more clear and reliable.

Comment: `more dynamic method would help with future maintenance` it is not true, any method which hides explicit list of all classes will requite more maintenance later because of learning curve